# Join by two pandas dataframes using slightly different strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have two distinct databases that complement each other, but the only association possible between them is their `name`. The problem is that their names are not fully equal:

Dataframe 1:

| Product name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 'Viazem XL 360mg' | 1234 |

Dataframe 2:

| Product name | AdministrationRoute |
| --- | --- |
| 'Viazem XL 360mg capsules' | 'Oral' |

This is just an example of how the same product can appear on both databases. How do I join both dataframes? I guess the solution could be through checking if the whole `name` from `dataframe 1` is in the `name` of the product from `dataframe 2`, but that also can happen the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You may use string similarity metrics to assess the similarity of two strings and use a threshold to classify them as the same or not. For example, [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) is a python extension for computing string edit distances and similarities, and has a couple of methods that may help you to compare the strings. With Jaro similarity:

```
from Levenshtein import jaro
jaro('Viazem XL 360mg', 'Viazem XL 360mg capsules')
```

gives you a score of 0.875, which is quite a good score in terms of string similarity. In the original documentation it says:

> The Jaro string similarity metric is intended for short strings like
> personal last names. It is 0 for completely different strings and 1
> for identical strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I have products with the same name but different numerical values i.e. `Viazem XL 120mg`, so using scores may not be the best approach

Comment: Then it would be very nice if you could add more examples from dataset on extreme cases. It is hard to guess what problems may occur. Assuming there may be some marks or incorrect spacings or varying capitalization, you could apply `re.sub(r'\W+', '', name.lower())` to the medicine _name_ then compare them with _in_ as the fastest way to look for substring as you have also thought. But this would not work for example if you had 'Viazem XL 360mg capsules' in one and 'Viazem XL capsules 360mg' in another. If that is the case, making a set from each and checking for intersections may work better.